# Calcular tempo de carregamento de uma página

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de medir o tempo de carregamento de uma página usando JavaScript. Como assim?

- Quando alguém acessar minha página eu quero começar a medir o tempo de carregamento.
- Caso este tempo de carregamento ultrapasse, por exemplo, 500 ms eu quero exibir um link sugerindo a utilização de uma versão mais simples da página, pois está claro pra mim que a conexão deste usuário é lenta.

Existe algum *script* que faça isso?

**EDIT**

Tive boas resposta, mas não tive uma resposta exatamente como eu esperava. Eu tenho certeza que existem abordagens mais elegantes do que colocar um timer na página. Eu quero identificar gargalos para chegar num padrão de excelência no quesito velocidade.

Achei interessante a abordagem usando o *window.performance.timing*.

Este exemplo no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808486/explanation-of-window-performance-javascript) aparentemente chega próximo do quê procuro. Alguém já utilizou esta abordagem?

**EDIT 2**

Para que eu não pareca chato nos comentários, gostaria de fornecer mais algumas informações:

O objeto *Date* do *JavaScript* resolve parte do meu problema, mas não com o nível de excelência que espero.

- Primeiro por que ele não é preciso;
- Segundo que com ele não consigo medir a latência da rede.

A latência é muito importante pois estou tomando uma decisão entre um serviço na nuvem ([www.parse.com](http://parse.com)) e um servidor de aplicação (*Java* + *Wildfly*) também na nuvem.

O parse me oferece uma velocidade de desenvolvimento fantástica, mas será que o tempo de resposta é satisfatório? Será que o *Wildfly*, mesmo estando também na nuvem, vai me responder com maisvelocidade? Preciso de métricas para isso, e o Date não vai me dar todas as métricas que quero.

Comment: `window.performance.timing` talvez seja uma boa via...

Comment: @Guill, acho que não carece da interrogação, o conteúdo tem um pergunta explícita. . . . Edgar, legal esta info que o Sergio passou; sugeriria talvez vc armazenar uma dezena de valores do timing em um objeto localStorage e poder fazer uma média.

Comment: @brasofilo achei interessante, vou testar os métodos passados até agora.

Comment: So enriquecendo o que o @sergio falou, achei interessante, e tem uma boa explicação aqui mesmo no SO em ingles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808486/explanation-of-window-performance-javascript

Comment: Abordagem elegante?

Comment: @Guill é pô. Gostei da sua resposta, ela funciona, mas vou aguardar mais abordagens. Gostaria de saber se alguém já utilizou uma abordagem com o *windows.performance*. Eu mesmo pretendo estudar isso, mas enquanto não arrumo tempo eu vou esperar por mais respostas. Só não pense que não gostei da sua resposta :), ela é boa e quero saber se pode surgir uma melhor ainda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar um *ping* utilizando o seu servidor, assumindo que ele esteja disponível e você use jQuery:

```
// Timer de Alta Resolução
hDPing = window.performance.now();

// Timer de Alta Resolução para browser baseados em WebKit
hDWKitPing = window.performance.webkitNow();

// Timer de resolução padrão
ping = new Date().getTime();

$.ajax({ 
    type: "HEAD",
    url: "http://server.com/ping.php",
    data: "",
    cache: false,
    success: function(output){ 
        hDPing = window.performance.now() - hDPing;
        hDWKitPing = window.performance.webkitNow() - hDWKitPing;
        ping = new Date().getTime() - ping;
    }
});
```

`window.performance.now()` é suportado no Google Chrome, Firefox 15 ou superior e no IE10.

Por ser uma requisição simples, o tempo de execução do *script* `<?php echo ""; ?>` não vai tomar tempo algum.

E no final, `ping`, `hpPing`, `hpWKitPing` vão retornar a latência geral (cliente -> servidor -> cliente). Em cima desses valores você pode fazer os cálculos e definir o que é uma velocidade aceitável e outras coisas.

Pode executar mais de um *ping* para realizar uma média e mais um milhar de possíveis métodos.

Answer (score 4):

Logo após a tag `<head>` de sua página, adicione o seguinte script:

```
<script>
    var time = new Date().getTime();
</script>
```

Antes do fechamento `</body>` o próximo script:

```
<script>
    time = (new Date().getTime()) - time; 
</script>
```

Para o caso do uso da jQuery pode substituir o script de antes do fechamento `</body>` pelo seguinte (agradecimento ao [Miguel Angelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1925/miguel-angelo) pelo comentário):

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        time = (new Date().getTime()) - time; 
    });
</script>
```

E `time` terá o seu tempo de carregamento medido em milissegundos.

### Exemplo

Veja o tempo que você demora para confirmar o alerta uma vez que o carregamento da página poder ser extremamente rápido:

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    var time = (new Date().getTime()) - start;
    $("p").text("A página foi renderizada em " + String(time) + " milissegundos...");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var start = new Date().getTime(); 
    alert("Espere e Aperte Enter");
</script>
<center>
    <h1>Página renderizada!</h1>
    <br />
    <p></p>
</center>
```

Comment: A solução é boa, porém, não é correta no caso em que existem scripts a ser carregados que estejam declarados dentro da tag head

Comment: Considero a opção apresentada no snippet (usando document ready) bem melhor que a descrita no texto (colocar um script antes do fechamento da tag body). Talvez seja ainda melhor combinar as duas, colocar o script `$("document").ready(function() ...` antes do fechamento do `body`, para fazer com que o handler que mede o tempo seja o último a ser executado.

Comment: Correções implementadas. Agradeço pelos comentários.

Comment: Apesar de resolver não é o tipo de solução que eu estava esperando. O código em si funciona, mas tenho que replica-lo em todas as páginas e nao é bem o que quero. Vou dar uma editada na pergunta.

Comment: Pode guardar o resultado em `localStorage`. Segundo a sua edição na pergunta, o que você precisa é medir a velocidade da conexão do requisitante.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta ja existia, vejam neste link e exemplo de código:

```
<script>
   var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
   $(window).load(function () {
       var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
       var millisecondsLoading = endTime - startTime;
       // Put millisecondsLoading in a hidden form field
       // or Ajax it back to the server or whatever.
   });
</script>
```

Fonte: [Page load time with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211414/page-load-time-with-jquery)